# How to read compacted javascript?

Tags: javascript

There are many compacted javascript source code in web and I am wonder how to transfer it to the normal code and make it readable?  Are there any exsited tools or scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://jsbeautifier.org/

But you will never get it really readable, because all comments and names will be screwed. You can get non-minified version for almost any free javascript file.

Comment: The website can reformat compress code quickly and there are normal format javascript code for almost open-source project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's a free library, you will most likely find the uncompressed version for download on the official website - this is the best choice when available. Otherwise, there really isn't a way to retrieve the exact original code because most variable names would have been replaced with meaningless one- or two- character strings. All the logic is still intact in the compacted script but it can quickly get very confusing to follow manually.